# Java StopWatch Applet Progression

Tags: java, time, applet, stopwatch

I have to create a Java Applet that replicates a stop watch. So far I have a running applet with a start/stop button. What I am unsure how to do is displaying the progression of the time going up and stopping when the stop/start button is pressed. Here is my code. Thank you!

```
   package stopwatch;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class stopwatch extends Applet implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Button start;
    Button stop;
    LocalDateTime localdt0;
    LocalDateTime localdt1;

    public void init(){
        start = new Button("Start");
        stop = new Button("Stop");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

        //start.setBounds(new Rectangle(20, 20, 100, 30));

        add(start, "North");
        add(stop, "South");
        stop.setEnabled(false);

        start.addActionListener(this);
        stop.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Duration d;
        String s;

        if (e.getSource() == start) {
            start.setEnabled(false);
            stop.setEnabled(true);
            localdt0 = LocalDateTime.now();
        }
        else {
            stop.setEnabled(false);
            start.setEnabled(true);
            localdt1 = LocalDateTime.now();
            d = Duration.between(localdt1, localdt0);
            s = d.toString();
            s += "";
        }
    }

    //  public void paint(Graphics g)
    //  {
    //      
    //  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you generally separate your business logic with the GUI interface, so if I were you I would make a StopWatch class that handles that part of it and simply use that object in this gui with fx "start/stop" methods.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do something like that. Thank You

Comment: I elaborated abit on my answer below, hope it helps. Play around with the code and make it fit your needs, it's alot more gratifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you generally separate your business logic with the GUI interface, so if I were you I would make a StopWatch class that handles that part of it and simply use that object in this gui with fx "start/stop" methods.

How to make a stopwatch class.. well there are a few ways. You could fx have a start method which takes an amount of seconds as a parameter, gets the current system time in miliseconds in the start method and runs a loop until the time exceeds the amount of time the user put in the parameter.

Basically you get the current time in miliseconds run a loop and do an if sentence in the loop saying something like.

EDIT:

Also remember that your class might need to extend the thread class so it can run properly and simultaneously with your gui.

```
public void start(int amountOfTime) {
  int startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  while (some boolean is true) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis()>=startTime+(amountOfTime*1000)) boolean = false;

  }
}
```

I added some code here you should be able to correct it to your liking and figure out the rest.

As for stopping it... you could simply make the loop dependant on a boolean and change it with the stop method or something similar.

As for showing it graphcially.. well you could just insert a label and keep updating it.

Comment: Alright I will try this, But where should I add that code into the file? Or just make it a new method.

Comment: You should create a completely new class in your project src folder and call it stopwatch or something. Then put the stop an start methods in there. In your GUI you have (the file you have now) you simply make an object of it and use its methods. If you have doubts about how to do these things I recommend reading up on classes and objects etc.

Comment: If you find your application freezes wen you start the stopwatch is because you need to extend the Thread class or implement the Runable interface. You can google it to read more on how, it's not too hard.

Comment: I will. I am just learning about applets now so It will take time to fully understand everything. Thanks